# Infinite loop when asynchronous action dispatched within useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I experienced an infinite loop after including a dispatch within useEffect in my code. I have checked a number of other similar questions but I don't seem to have my hand around the problem
My component looks thus:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@material-ui/core/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { Typography, Paper, Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchInvestment } from '../../action/apirequest';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    table: {
      minWidth: 650,
    },
  });

  const tableHeading = ['Title', 'Amount', 'Start Date', 'End Date', 'Type'];
  const displayedResult = [{title: 'mike',amount: 'startDate', endDate: 'mike',type: 'mike' }, {title: 'mike',amount: 'startDate', endDate: 'mike',type: 'mike' }];
  const tableDataKey = ['title', 'amount','startDate', 'endDate', 'type'];
const InvestmentTable=(props)=>{
    const classes = useStyles();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(()=>dispatch(fetchInvestment()));

    const tableData = useSelector(state=>state).dataReducer.dataArray;
    console.log('data', tableData);
    return(<Grid container={true} ><Grid justify="center" alignItems="center" item xs={12} > <TableContainer component={Paper}>
        <Typography className="typo-table" variant="h5">{props.heading}</Typography>
        <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell className="table-head">S/N</TableCell>
              {tableHeading.map(item=>(<TableCell className="table-head" key={item} align="left"> {item}</TableCell>))}
              <TableCell className="table-head" align="left">Options</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
          {displayedResult.map((row, i) => (
              <TableRow key={row.id}>
                <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                  {i+1}
                </TableCell>
                {tableDataKey.map((cell)=>(<TableCell key={cell} align="left">{row[cell]}</TableCell>))}
                <TableCell align="left"></TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
      </Grid></Grid>)

}

export default InvestmentTable;
```

The asynchronous action dispatched through useDispatch looks thus:

```js
export const fetchInvestment=()=>{
  return function(dispatch, getState){
    const {authToken, userId} = getState().authReducer;
    token= authToken;
      const data= {};
      data.userId = userId;
      const url = 'investment/fetchAll';
      apiCall(url, data, dispatch,'post').then((data)=>{
        try{
          if(data.status=== 200){
            console.log('success',data);
            dispatch(ArrayLoaded(data.data.data));
          }
        }
        catch(error){
          console.log('returnedError',error);

        }
      }, (error)=>{console.log(error)});
      
      
  }
}




const apiCall= async (url, data, dispatch, type="get")=>{
    dispatch(requestStarted());
    const requestUrl = appUrl+url;
    let response;
    try{
    if(type === "get"){
        response = await axios(requestUrl, header());
      }
      else {
        response= await axios.post(requestUrl, data, header());
      }
      //toast.success()
      dispatch(requestComplete());
      return response;
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error);
        console.log(error.response.status);
        console.log(error.response.data.message);
        //if(error.response.status === 401){
          toast.error(error.response.data.message);
          //dispatch(notify(error.response.data.message))
          dispatch(requestComplete());
        //}
    }
}
```

I will like to know what I am doing wrongly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `useEffect` incorrectly. You must supply it a dependency and in your case if you want it to run just once give it an empty array like this :

```
   useEffect(()=>{
    dispatch(fetchInvestment())
    },[])
```

What this essentially means is your useEffect does not have any dependencies to look for and thus will run only once. If you want it to change based on if some state changes then you pass that state in that dependency array.